# Альтернатива for, но более производительней

Tags: r

У меня есть цикл. Индекс **(i)**, который перебирается, нигде не используется. Цикл нужен только для того, чтобы код внутри него выполнился **n раз**.

Пример:

```
a <- 1
n <- 50

for(i in 1:n){
  a <- 5*a
  b <- a+2
  c <- a+b
}
```

Но если **n будет** равняться, к примеру, **1 000 000**, замедлит ли это выполнение кода?

Есть ли альтернатива обычному циклу for?

Comment: Зачем выполнять один и тот же код n раз? Какая стоит задача?

Comment: В R есть много альтернатив `for`, только что вы делаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, есть. Цикл for в R существует скорее для того "чтобы было". В большинстве случаев можно обойтись без него и работать будет гораздо быстрее. Есть множество альтернатив, но начать следует, думаю, с функций семейства apply
В вашем случае будет что-то типа такого:

```
n <- 50
sapply( 1:n, function(x) { код который будет исполнен n раз} )
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А какие еще есть альтернативы кроме sapply, foreach, рекурсий?
Не подскажите как можно заменить два вложенных цикла не прибегая к sapply(,FUN=sapply)?

Comment: Думаю в двойном вызове apply-функциий нет ничего зазорного. Все зависит от решаемой задачи. Но возможно имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону библиотеки dplyr и оператора %>%

Answer (score 2):

Более подходящими вариантов вижу функцию `replicate`, которое позволяет повторить код заданное число раз. Результаты выполнения будут возвращены в виде списка или вектора.

В R также есть конструкция `repeat`:

```
repeat {
    statement
    if (condition) break
}
```

В данном контексте `repeat` является аналогом `while(TRUE)`.

И последнее, циклы в R не являются чем-то плохим, просто их довольно часто используют неэффективно, так как пытаются копировать код из других языком программирования без учёта особенностей R.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!